# hibernate java curiosity - after saving the object, both the object to save and the saved one have id set

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

I have the following simple code:

```
@Test
public void saveExpense() {
    // Create dummy Expense object i.e. { "description": "Short Description", "date": etc } 
    Expense expenseToSave = ExpenseHelper.createExpense("Short Description", new Date(), user);

    Expense savedExpense = expenseService.save(expenseToSave);

    // What is strange, is that here, both expenseToSave and savedExpense have id set to 1 for example; after save the expense should have an id; 

    Expense expected = ExpenseHelper.createExpense("Short Description", new Date(), user);
    // Check if expected object is equal to the saved one
    Assert.assertTrue(expected.equals(expenseService.findByDescription("Short Description")));
}
```

Normally I would expect that expenseToSave to be without id and savedExpense with id, but both have id after save. Why?

That made another variable to be necessary and complicate the test.

Thanks.

Comment: See whether `expenseToSave == savedExpense`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how the Hibernate Session.save() method is specified. From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/):

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated
>   identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if
>   the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update".

IDs are the mechanism how Hibernate differentiates between persisted and transient objects, and how it identifies specific objects. Therefore, the ID is set early in the persistence step, as for example cyclic references in an object tree are resolved via IDs while persisting.

What differentiates the returned object vs. the original object is that the returned object is attached to the Hibernate session. For example, with active cascading, contained entities (e.g. in a one-to-many collection) are now persistent instances as well in the returned object.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that

```
void EntityManager#persist(java.lang.Object entity)
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29)

Persists the given object by changing the object passed in and does *not* return a persisted copy - I suspect your `ExpenseHelper` to return the original object additionally so that you receive the same object via return as you already have by passing it in.

This follows a common anti-pattern for a kind of unified behaviour of DAO to be something like

```
public T create(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.persist(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

to get a kind of synchronicity with saving something

```
public T save(T entity) {
    return this.entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

Where

```
<T> T EntityManager#merge(T entity)
```

does indeed merge and pass you the merged entity.

Comment: So it is passed by reference, then? Cool.

Comment: You can always change an objects contents you get via parameters, the difference is that JPA spec here explicitely defines that entities can not be immutable objects because they will be changed through persisting.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on Hibernate mapping of the Expense entity, or implementation of ExpenseHelper class.

Also, take a look on Expense.equals() implementation.

Comment: Hi, thx for the aswer; seems rezonable. Waht ExpenseHelper does is to create a new instance of Expense and return it, so I suppose is about Hibernate; I was courious how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement:
`Expense savedExpense = expenseService.save(expenseToSave);`
the value of the `savedExpense` object will depend on what your are doing in the save method. Usually save methods don't return an object. You already have a reference to the object that  you just saved (`expenseToSave`) available to you. And you are trying to assert that your `expected` object `equals` the object that was saved, which is fine. So I am not sure what the purpose of returning an object in `expenseService.save(expenseToSave)`

Also, note that the id of the object `expenseToSave` would have been populated by your ORM (Hibernate, I assume) based on your configuration, when you save it. There is no need to return this object or another object in the save method.